# Some doubts about @property in python 3

Tags: python

In order not to extend myself too much I will give a basic and hypothetical example of what I am trying to do.
Suppose the following class:

```
class foo():
   def __init__(self):
      self.keywords = []

   ## this method returns the entire list
   def get_keywords(self):
      return self.keywords

   def set_keywords(self, value):
      self.keywords.append(value)
```

But I want to code this in a pythonic way using the `@property` decorator.
My (wrong) attempt to do this:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = []

    @property
    def key(self):
        return self.__key

    @key.setter
    def key(self, value):
        self.__key.append(value)
```

So, whats is wrong in my attempt ? 
ps: English is not my native language and I hope my doubt is understandable.

Comment: `self.__key = []`…!?

Comment: giving the trace of the observed error would help

Comment: BTW, it would feel somewhat odd that `f.key = 'bar'; print(f.key)` would output a list instead of just `'bar'`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, `self.set_keywords` *only* appends to an existing list; it does not let you initialize the value of `keywords` to an arbitrary list. This restriction is preserved in your `property`-based code, which means you cannot assign directly to `self.key`; you have to initialize the underlying list in `__init__` directly.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # self.key = [] is equivalent to `self.__key.append([])`, but
        # self.__key doesn't exist yet. (And would be wrong even if it did.)
        self.__key = []

    @property
    def key(self):
        return self.__key

    @key.setter
    def key(self, value):
        self.__key.append(value)
```

However, this means an assignment like `self.key = 3` doesn't actually perform what most people would expect of an assignment. It doesn't overwrite the old value, it adds to it instead. Use the setter to provide a fixed list, but a different method to add to an existing one.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__keys = []

    @property
    def keys(self):
        return self.__keys

    @keys.setter
    def keys(self, values):
        self.__keys = values

    def add_key(self, value):
        self.__key.append(value)
```

And finally, it's not necessarily more Pythonic to use a property if you don't actually do any sort of extra work or validation in the getter or setter. If all you are doing is wrapping access to an underlying value, just let the value be used directly.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keys = []

self.keys = [1,2,3]
print(self.keys)
self.keys.append(4)
# etc
```

The nice thing about properties is that if you *start* by allowing direct access to `keys`, then *nothing* about how you use `keys` changes if you later decide to replace it with a property.

Comment: Now I understand my error, I should only use the ```@foo.setter``` when I want to do assignments like ```f.x = value```,  right ? 
The way Python handles encapsulation is a bit strange, but I'm getting used to it gradually. Thank you very much.

Comment: Right, the setter is called to handle direct assignments, so the basic semantics of assignment should be preserved.

Comment: "And finally, it's not necessarily more Pythonic to use a property if you don't actually do any sort of extra work or validation in the getter or setter." I wouldn't hedge here, that is not Pythonic. Maybe if you were implementing some abc that use `abstractproperty`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Depends how you classify omitting a setter to make a property read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._key = []

    @property
    def key(self):
        return self._key

    @key.setter
    def key(self, value):
        self._key = value
```

Here are my two cents:

- Rename the class `foo` to `Foo`
- You can't initialize `self.key`, as this is the property, so initialize the correct variable in the constructor (i.e. `__init__`)
- *Private* vars are prefixed with one `_` scope and not two (two `__` are Python internals)
- I suppose you rather want `my_instance.key = ['spam', 'eggs']` to replace the `foo._key` value than extend it. Because this is kind of a "setter" and that would result in a weird behaviour, or at least another developer won't expect that behaviour from that setter/function

However, and that's important: As long as you're only doing this, you won't need properties. You can simply initialize `self.keys` in the constructor and froget about the property and setter function. Later on, when you want to change the behaviour, you can still add the property and setter. That's one reason why we've properties in Python, so that you won't have to refactor your whole code in case "a bit more logic" comes into place.

Btw. if you're really depending everything on those dict functions, you might also want to inherit your class from the `dict` class. Depends what you're up to.

Comment: On your third point: no, Python internals are `__dunder__` attributes. Private (name mangled) attributes are `__xyz`. The *convention* for "protected" attributes is a single leading underscore.

Comment: @deceze name mangling is not the same thing as private. And honestly think speaking of protected just muddies the water, a single underscore sends the same signal to readers of the code as *private*, i.e. don't touch this. Double underscores almost say the opposite: in a subclasses, feel free to use this name and don't worry about messing up internal details

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you want to apply terms like “private” at all to Python, then IMO a single underscore is equivalent to what most other languages call “protected” and double underscores equal “private”. Otherwise the use of those terms is pretty arbitrary.